# Facebook SDK: retrieve User information in my Android application

Tags: facebook, mobile-application, android, userinfo

I am new in Android Development and I know there are many examples about what I am asking but I can't really understand them and the one in facebook doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/ is very complicated

I integrated Facebook in my code as below

```
package com.example.museum;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    Facebook fb;
    ImageView pic, button, signup;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    TextView welcome;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

        welcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);

        sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null){

            fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if (expires != 0){

            fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }





        button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);


        pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture_pic);
        signup = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.signup);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),One.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        userInfo();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void userInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");



        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
            signup.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

            //pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            JSONObject obj = null;
            URL img_value = null;




            try {

                String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);

                String id = obj.optString("id");
                String name = obj.optString("name");

                Log.d("NAME", name);

                 // getting email of the user
                //String email = obj.optString("email");

                //for (int i = 0; i< 100 ; i++)Log.d("E_MAIL", email);

                welcome.setText("Welcome to Museum, " + name);

//              img_value = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?height=100&type=normal&width=100&redirect=0");
//              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
//              pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
//              pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);


            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Error", "FacebookError");
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Error", "JSONException");
                e.printStackTrace();


            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Error", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                for (int i = 0; i< 50 ; i++)Log.d("Error", "Exception");
            }



        }else{
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);





        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            // button close our session - log out of facebook
            try {
                fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                userInfo();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else {
            //login to facebook 
            fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fbError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    userInfo();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}






}
```

And I need to retrieve user information such as his e-mail, his location, his birthday and most important the pages he like and I know I must use permissions can you please tell me how would I do that.

Any Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new callback request. like this:

```
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(Login.this);
    openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));
    openRequest.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser gUser,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (gUser != null) {
                                    String email = gUser.getProperty("email").toString();
                                    String firstName = gUser.getFirstName();
                                    String lastName = gUser.getLastName();
                                    String username = gUser.getUsername();
                                    String birthday = gUser.getBirthday();
                                }
                            }

                        });
                request.executeAsync();

            }
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: instead of my method userInfo() you mean or in addition to it ? where to add it I am a little bit confused

Comment: @مروانعلىفهمى you should be able to put that inside of your `userInfo()` method

Comment: so what is "user" is it a bundle ? because I don't understand what are doing !

Comment: I did this and tried to output it in the log and I got nothing... are sure I just replace this what is in userInfo() and it works

Comment: @مروانعلىفهمى What are you trying to log?

Comment: these parameters the first name and last name for instance and they don't appear in the logcat